# ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy , ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, macos, numpy, python-poetry

I`m using python poetry(https://python-poetry.org/) for dependency management in my project.

Though when I`m running `poetry install`, its giving me below error.

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I`m having python 3.9 installed in my laptop.
I installed numpy 1.21.5 using `pip install numpy`, I even tried to down version it to 1.19.5.

Though I`m getting the same error.

I found out many people are getting `ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy` this error in python 3.10, they solved it by down versioning python to 3.9, though that didnt working for me.

Comment: Having this same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @AdityaSingh I just updated to the latest version of `numpy` with no problem as follows: `pip install -U numpy`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following steps:-

1. I updated the pyproject.toml(This file contains all the library/dependency/dev dependency)with the numpy version that I installed using `pip install numpy` command.
   [image]
2. Run `poetry lock` to update poetry.lock file(contains details information about the library)
   [image]
3. Run `poetry install` again, & it should work fine.

- In a nutshell, you just have to install the correct version of numpy [Click me to check the compatibility](https://endoflife.date/numpy#:%7E:text=NumPy%20stopped%20supporting%20Python%203.7,support%20Python%203.8%20and%20above.)
- And then install the required version using `pip install numpy==version`.
  **Example:**
  To install NumPy version 1.23.5, use the following-
  `pip install numpy==1.23.5`

If you are having any problems, you can comment.
I`ll try to answer it.

Comment: This worked for me as well. The error came with numpy version 1.21.2 but not with 1.22.3.  Please consider, that newer numpy versions, e.g. 1.22.3 requires Python 3.8 or newer. I had to update my pyproject.toml to respect this as well.

Comment: Where should this pyproject.toml file be located? As I can't find it...

Comment: @Nelis, It's in the root directory.

Comment: how to update the `pyproject.toml`?

Answer (score 4):

I had this trying to install numpy with PyPy on macOS.

I solved the issue by first running `brew doctor`, which showed that my Command Line Tools (XCode) were outdated. Then I just followed the instructions to update them:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

This solved the issue.

---

My configuration:

- macOS 12.2.1 Monterey

```sh
> python --version
Python 3.8.12 (9ef55f6fc369, Oct 25 2021, 05:10:01)
[PyPy 7.3.7 with GCC Apple LLVM 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
```

Comment: Xcode is required for numpy?

Comment: Xcode command line tools includes commands like `make`, stuff that's probably included by default on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by install the right version of numpy
check the compatibility here https://matplotlib.org/stable/devel/min_dep_policy.html

and then install it by
pip3 install -v numpy==[version]

Answer (score -4):

### Numpy error solved

```
Error: failed to build wheels for numpy which is required to install project.tmol
```

This error cause due to outdated numpy version simply run this command

> MATHLAB = "m" pip install numpy

`

**My python version:**
*Python -V=3.9*

*It doesn't works in se case but most of the time works.*

**If you are working in `venv`then try to install numpy in venv.**
**Then run your code it will be working
Fine**.