# ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy.Failed to build numpy

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot on Python, I decided to upload it to heroku hosting and every time I get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
            Failed to build numpy
            ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
            [end of output]
        
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
      × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> See above for output.
      
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed
```

I think it will be useful for you too:

```
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.5
      To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.10.5
-----> Installing pip 22.1.2, setuptools 60.10.0 and wheel 0.37.1
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
```

numpy:1.22.4

I also reinstalled numpy and python.  Any ideas for this?

Comment: It may be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70566445/13962953

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Python: discord.py) ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497319/python-discord-py-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-multidict-yarl-which-use)