# Unable to pip install mlagents due to an error with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I'm trying to install mlagents with this command:
`py -m pip install mlagents`

But it is giving me this error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [198 lines of output]
      setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.
        warnings.warn(
      Running from numpy source directory.
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
      Cythonizing sources
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
        libraries blis not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE

      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        libraries satlas not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\GorillaPenguin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gastdmq4\numpy_82c921eb1d4c4750852b691ac83f4d90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_info:
        libraries blas not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\GorillaPenguin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gastdmq4\numpy_82c921eb1d4c4750852b691ac83f4d90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\GorillaPenguin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gastdmq4\numpy_82c921eb1d4c4750852b691ac83f4d90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:2026: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
        NOT AVAILABLE

      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      flame_info:
        libraries flame not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in D:\Unity\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\venv\lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in D:\Unity\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\venv\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in D:\Unity\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\venv\lib
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in D:\Unity\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\venv\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in D:\Unity\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\venv\lib
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in D:\Unity\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\venv\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in D:\Unity\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\venv\lib
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in D:\Unity\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\venv\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
        libraries lapack not found in ['D:\\Unity\\ReinforcementLeaning_InfoProject\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\GorillaPenguin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gastdmq4\numpy_82c921eb1d4c4750852b691ac83f4d90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\GorillaPenguin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gastdmq4\numpy_82c921eb1d4c4750852b691ac83f4d90\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1858: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        NOT AVAILABLE

      numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
        FOUND:
          language = c
          define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

      Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
      C:\Users\GorillaPenguin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e4taaz4o\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm on a Windows 10, using the latest version of pip and python 3.10.8.

Edit: Apparently the installation uses the cached version of NumPy, even after deleting the pip cache folder..

I have also installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 as it is one of the last lines of the error. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70565965/error-failed-building-wheel-for-numpy-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-numpy Related Question?

Comment: Their solutions didn't work

Comment: There may be a related issue at the mlagents github

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't answer your comment because I don't have enough rep:
`NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.` 
After I read your error, I found this line...so it seems to me you either have to downgrade python or update numpy (most recent version is 1.24)
Related: [NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458399/numpy-1-21-2-may-not-yet-support-python-3-10)
I also found this issue on github: [mlagents-envs 0.22.0 requires numpy<1.19.0,>=1.14.1, but you'll have numpy 1.19.4 which is incompatible.](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/issues/4693)

Comment: I just checked, and I have the latest version of NumPy (1.24.1), which is weird given the line you mentioned in the error. An according to the official NumPy website, "This release supports Python versions 3.8-3.11"

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it by uninstalling everything and following the official installation tutorial using Python 3.9

Comment: I was also unable to pip install mlagents on mac unless using python=3.9

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this problem still exists in 21/01/2024 on the release_21, so I feel it is necassary to explain a work around:
Firstly, follow the [installation guide](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/develop/docs/Installation.md) until the part of cloning the repository. After cloning the repository, you need to adjust the version of the numpy as follows:

1. Go to repository location
2. Open the "ml-agents-envs" folder
3. Open setup.py in a text editor
4. Search for numpy==
5. Change the value after the numpy== to 1.23.5

The version number is copied from this [commit](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/commit/f3dc8f615044c9226c7e7ed308e0aadc1def3b4d) to a side branch of the project.

After following those simple steps, just carry on with the installation **from the cloned project**